# Add active class to current page link based on URL not working with localhost

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink, navigation, anchor

I know this is a simple jQuery task, I've done it a million times but I can not seem to add an "active" class to the menu item below based on page URL. Is it an issue with using http://localhost:8888/? Is it an issue with having 2 index pages, 1 php 1 html? How can I target the subnav also?

```
  <nav class="header-menu menu">
                <ul>
                    <li class="menu-item-has-children">
                        <a href="/expertise">
                            <span class="nav-text">Expertise</span>
                            <span class="icon-down-arrow-small "></span>
                        </a>

                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <li><a href="">Meet our Team</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Our Process</a></li>
                        </ul>

                    </li>
                    <li class="menu-item-has-children">
                        <a href="/projects">
                            <span class="nav-text">Projects</span>
                            <span class="icon-down-arrow-small "></span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <li><a href="">Meet our Team</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Our Process</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Our Process</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Our Process</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/about">
                            <span class="nav-text">About</span>
                            <span class="icon-down-arrow-small "></span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <span class="nav-text">Insights</span>
                            <span class="icon-down-arrow-small "></span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <span class="nav-text">Careers</span>
                            <span class="icon-down-arrow-small "></span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>


      $(function() {
     var url = location.origin + location.pathname;
     $('nav a[href^="' + url + '"]')
      .closest('li')
       .addClass('active');
    });
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I updated the code.

Comment: Your `href` attribute doesn't contain `location.origin`, so your selector doesn't match.